# Make a global variable in Visual Basic for Applications

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

In VBA for Access, how do I make a global variable that I can access and change anywhere?

Comment: Add a Module, at the top `public variablename as datatype_you_want`

Comment: just to throw in that the more code lines a project has the less `Public` variables should be used in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare a variable at Global scope by declaring it in a Standard Module or a predeclared class module such as a Worksheet, UserForm or PreDeclared class, using the `Public` keyword:

```
Public myVar As String
```

You can also declare a Global variable using the now deprecated, but still valid `Global` syntax, which is functionally the same as `Public`

```
Global myVar As String
```

But note that declaring a variable with `Public` or `Global` will make the variable accessible across your entire project *AND* to any project that refers to that project, and even if your project is protected, a user could still query the variable from the Immediate window.

If you must have a variable that is available across your project, but only that project, then you should declare the variable in a standard module, and include an `Option Private Module` statement to make the module private to the project, but its variables as Public to the project only.

```
Option Private Module
Public myVar As String
```

Comment: Is there documentation of the deprecation of `global` in favor of `public`?