# VBA keyword "global"

Tags: vba, global, keyword

I have some constants declared in my VBA code as:

```
global const variable = value
```

These declarations are working properly, by which I mean they don't cause an error and the constants are used in other modules without error.

In reviewing the scope of my variables, I've looked at the Microsoft documentation to ensure that I'm doing it right. But lo and behold, I find that Microsoft doesn't even define `global` as a keyword! The official list of keywords for VBA does not include `global`:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/keywords-visual-basic-for-applications

Furthermore, the syntax for the `const` statement, given at:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement

is:

```
[ Public | Private ] Const constname [ As type ] = expression
```

which does not allow `global` as a modifier. This should mean that my declarations should be throwing a compiler error.

Moreover, three Microsoft pages about scope in VBA do not include the word "global" anywhere in their text:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/scope
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-scope-and-visibility
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-the-lifetime-of-variables

I found one page of Microsoft documentation that refers to a keyword `global`, which is in the context of defining namespaces:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/program-structure/namespaces

Because of that, the list of VBA keywords linked above is wrong for not including `global`.

There is a *Stack Overflow* answer that states, "`Public` and `Global` are nearly identical in their function, however `Global` can only be used in standard modules, whereas `Public` can be used in all contexts (modules, classes, controls, forms etc.) `Global` comes from older versions of VB and was likely kept for backwards compatibility, but has been wholly superseded by `Public`.":

- *[What is the difference between Dim, Global, Public, and Private as Modular Field Access Modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815547/what-is-the-difference-between-dim-global-public-and-private-as-modular-field/#3815797)* (answer)

And there is another *Stack Overflow* answer that describes the keyword `global` as "now deprecated, but still valid":

- *[Make a global variable in Visual Basic for Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39639488/make-a-global-variable-in-visual-basic-for-applications/#39640049)* (answer)

If those answers are correct, then I should change my code to replace `global` with `public`. But is there some documentation of the deprecation of `global` and the fact that it actually does still remain as a working keyword?

Comment: If you're asking for documentation, that's off-topic for SO. And yes, the answers you link to are correct.

Comment: Where is the place to ask for documentation?

Comment: I'm not sure but see point 4 of [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just a quick comment to say that while BigBen is right, you presented your question well - I wish more people would!

Comment: I'm not sure you're even going to find documentation about this. There are other instances of deprecated yet still valid, e.g. the `Buttons` collection within the Excel VBA Object Model. Side note, I'd take MSFT docs with a grain of salt as they can have ... issues.

Comment: Another side note, two of your links are VB.Net, not VBA.

Comment: Finding VB.NET documentation when looking for VBA documentation does seem to happen quite often. Even MS is confused by them, it seems.